# 301 Redirect to HTTPS causing all non-homepage, non-HTTPS pages to redirect to homepage

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I have a website that i just added an SSL certificate to. I added the following to .htaccess to redirect all non-HTTPS URLs to the HTTPS version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.co.uk [R=301,L]
```

I also wanted all non-www version of the site to redirect to www version so i added the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myurl.co.uk
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then, to help with SEO, i turned on URL rewriting (in Joomla, which I'm using) so now my URLs show as `https://www.myurl.co.uk/about` instead of `https://www.myurl.co.uk/index.php/about`.

I noticed however that when a link to my site is clicked (from Google for example) that still uses the old URL structure, it will always take the visitor to the homepage instead of the page they clicked on. So a visitor clicking on `www.myurl.co.uk/index.php/about` should be taken to `https://www.myurl.co.uk/about` but they are instead taken directly to `https://www.myurl.co.uk` (the homepage).

I tried adding the following for every page on my site:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php/about https://www.myurl.co.uk/about
```

...but this didn't fix the issue.

I'm very inexperienced with .htaccess. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Change `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.co.uk [R=301,L]
` to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]` like the second rule (the `$1` is key). Then read up on how these work. :-)

Comment: and don't forget to clear your cache! You're likely being shown cached versions of your URLs.

Comment: @ceejayoz that worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For meeting all 3 requirements i.e. `(http -> https, non-www -> www, /index.php/ removal)` you can use this single rule but **make sure this rule is placed at top before all other rules**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index\.php/. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php/)?(.*)$ https://www.myurl.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

- Avoiding multiple redirect rules will be good not just for SEO purpose but for client experience also.
- Don't use `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` rules while using `mod_rewrite` based rules.
- Make sure you completely clear your browser cache while testing this change.